# javascript - how to combine a static value and a dynamic value to get the value of an existing string

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

```
var a_0, a_1, a_2 = 0;

function onclick( id ) { 
   // id is either 0,1 or 2

   // echos 'a_0', 'a_1' or 'a_2', but I need it to echo "0".
   alert( 'a_' + id ); 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've tried alert(a_+id) as well and it says "a_" is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of declaring `a_0`, `a_1`, and `a_2` as global variables, put them in an object:

```
var a_x = {
    a_0: 0,
    a_1: 0,
    a_2: 0
}
```

Then you can access those properties like this: `a_x["a_" + id]`.

Comment: @nybbler I actually consider that a drawback. I still have this nagging feeling that `with` can be used somehow, as well.

Comment: I think I read you wrong...You consider *not* using eval to be a drawback? No need to use `with` (how would you?) or to complicate a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

instead of naming your vars a_0, a_1 etc, use an array

```
var a=[];
a[0]=a[1]=a[2]=0;

function onclick(id){
  alert(a[id]);
}
```

Comment: i was just typing that out for example sake that's not my actual code but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use eval()

```
alert(eval('a_'+id));
```

eval() isn't usually recommended, though, but it depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: eval() was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you trust the event source, you could do this:

```
alert(eval('a_'+id))
```

Comment: Remember: eval is *evil*. Also, how can you trust an onclick event source to not be tampered with?

Comment: I'd trust it if the site had no form inputs.